# Onscreen keyboard with RSA Authentication Agent on WIndows

Tags: windows, security, hardware, rsa, securid

I'm attempting to integrate a touch panel into our secured environment. As such, the touchpanel requires that the user login via RSA SecurID. Unfortunately, there is no exposed keyboard for the user to type their credentials into the login prompt.

Is there any way to expose an onscreen keyboard (Windows or third-party) during the login prompt so my users can login to the touchpanel?

Answer (score 1):

The file you want is **C:\Windows\System32\OSK.Exe**

Run Group Policy (Start > Run > GPEdit.MSC).

Go to Computer Configuration; Windows Settings; Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)
double-click on Startup.

Click on the button Show Files... and in the newly opened window

right click and create a new text file.

Rename to osk.bat

Right click & edit the file

put in it the following line:

C:\Windows\System32\OSK.Exe (check this is the correct path for the machine you’re using!!)

Save & close the file

close it’s folder window

in the Start Properties dialog click Add...

type OSK.bat in the script window

Select OK twice

Still in Group Policy, go to:

Computer Configuration; Administrative Templates; System; Scripts

on the right pane, select Run startup scripts synchronously

double click on this option

change to Enabled (This will make sure the logon process will continue even though the script 
has not ended).

Select OK

Shut group policy

Shutdown PC

Restart system - the on-screen keyboard will be available about 5-10 secs after the logon screen occurs.

Put any other access tools into the startup folder as normal